# Ошибка в запросе из нескольких таблиц PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql

База хранит данные сервиса по хранению задач. У задачи есть автор, время создания, описание, прикрепленные файлы и все в таком духе. У задачи также есть комментарии которые могут оставлять и другие пользователи не только автор, и у комментариев тоже есть прикрепленные файлы. И мне нужен такой запрос, по которому я смогу восстановить весь контекст задачи, с ее файлами, комментариями и их файлами, и авторами комментариев.

Есть система таблиц:

users

```
user_id |       username       |       password       |             email              |    role    
--------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------------------+------------
```

tasks

```
 code_task | user_id |                     name_task                      |          description          |   state    |       category       |     create_time     
-----------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+----------------------+---------------------
```

comments

```
 code_comment | code_task |   body_comment    |     create_time     | user_id 
--------------+-----------+-------------------+---------------------+---------
```

files_comments

```
 file_id |  file_path   | code_comment 
---------+--------------+--------------
```

files_tasks

```
 file_id |  file_path  | code_task 
---------+-------------+-----------
```

Я начал делать запрос который выгружает всю информацию по какой-то задаче по ее `code_task` рассчитывая получить:

```
       username       |                     name_task                      |      description      |   state    |   body_comment    |  file_path  |  file_path   
----------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+------------+-------------------+-------------+--------------
```

Создание псевдонима для `file_path` отдельная проблема...

Я делаю запрос : (2 это код задачи)

```
select u.username, t.name_task, t.description, t.state, c.body_comment, ft.file_path, fc.file_path from users as u
inner join tasks as t on t.code_task = '2'
inner join files_tasks as ft on ft.code_task = t.code_task
inner join comments as c on t.code_task = c.code_task and t.user_id = c.user_id
inner join files_comments as fc on c.code_comment = fc.code_comment;
```

И получаю совершенно не съедобный результат:

```
       username       |                     name_task                      |      description      |   state    |   body_comment    |  file_path  |  file_path   
----------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+------------+-------------------+-------------+--------------
 pavel                | my task 01                                         | description for check | open       | i am body comment | \a\b\c.e    | \my_path.txt
 slava                | my task 01                                         | description for check | open       | i am body comment | \a\b\c.e    | \my_path.txt
 pavel                | my task 01                                         | description for check | open       | i am body comment | \a\h.txt    | \my_path.txt
 slava                | my task 01                                         | description for check | open       | i am body comment | \a\h.txt    | \my_path.txt
 pavel                | my task 01                                         | description for check | open       | i am body comment | \a\text.txt | \my_path.txt
 slava                | my task 01                                         | description for check | open       | i am body comment | \a\text.txt | \my_path.txt
```

Проблема получаемых данных в том что не понятно какие файлы к какому комментарию относится, а может он к задаче прикреплен.

Мне нужен запрос по уникальному `code_task` в ответ должна получиться структура которая даст возможность восстановить задачу на UI стороне с заголовком, телом, статусом, именем автора, файлами приложенными к задаче, и файлами приложенными к комментариям так чтобы было понятно какой файл к какому комментарию относится, или к самой задаче.

Если бросаются в глаза какие-нибудь ошибке в архитектуре самой БД, буду признателен за конструктивную критику.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT (fieldset)
FROM users u,
     /* users u2, */
     tasks t,
     comments c,
     files_comments fc,
     files_tasks ft
WHERE u.user_id = t.user_id 
  AND c.code_task = t.code_task 
  AND c.code_comment = fc.code_comment 
  AND t.code_task = ft.code_task 
  /* AND c.user_id = u2.user_id */
  AND t.code_task = '2'
```

**UPD:**

> комментарии которые не имеют прикрепленных файлов не выводятся

```
SELECT (fieldset)
FROM users u
INNER JOIN tasks t ON u.user_id = t.user_id AND t.code_task = '2'
LEFT JOIN files_tasks ft ON t.code_task = ft.code_task
LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.code_task = t.code_task
/* INNER JOIN users u2 ON c.user_id = u2.user_id */
LEFT JOIN files_comments fc ON c.code_comment = fc.code_comment
```

Comment: не работает указывает на ошибку в слове fieldset

Comment: @Павел приведенный запрос подразумевает, что вместо `(fieldset)` вы подставите необходимые вам поля.

Comment: @Павел ... а также при необходимости уберёте комментарии в коде запроса, чтобы видеть авторов комментариев.

Comment: @Akina пардон затупил, да только теперь комментарии которые не имеют прикрепленных файлов не выводятся только с файлами((( нельзя ли как то это поправить?